# Toyota Camry running out of oil

Tags: toyota, oil, camry

I serviced my Toyota Camry three weeks ago and put 4 litres of mobile oil in. It's three weeks now and I am short of oil again, and this has been the case for the last 4 months. I bought 8 litres of oil.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

You need to get this investigated.

There must be evidence of where this oil is going either traces of oil on the ground or smoke out the exhaust etc.

But to use this amount is telling you something serious needs to be checked and corrected.

Answer (score 2):

I cant make a great diagnosis without a little more information, is there a puddle of oil below your car at any time? I cant add comments to clarify issues with you but i will do the best i can with this information.

In my experience this is a good indicator its time for a compression test. Theres only 3 things that make that much oil dissapear;

1. Big external leak
2. Worn out piston rings
3. Blown headgasket

A short term remedy would be to use thicker oil. I know that engine fsm allows for 10w-30, dealerships will use 15w-40 in these too if your in a warm climate this will at least slow down the oil consumption.